# Poner autoplay, loop embed youtube, y quitar enlace en el logo que redirige al video?

Tags: html5

He intentado de todo, pero no logro.

```
<iframe id="video-background" width="100%" height="600" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RO0uEPNCNU4?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=3-PnmmzF6NY&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: No es posible, ademas la opcion showinfo que estas utilizandp y que esconde la información del video va a dejar de funcionar a partir del 25 de septiembre. Porqué no hospedar tu mismo el video y utilizar la etiqueta video?

Comment: Muchas gracias brother